# Hovering the "sign up" button in the top navigation to expand the button causes other parts of navigation menu to move. How to prevent that?

Tags: html, css

While I was making top navigation for the website, I decided to add some animation for hovering the sign up button.The problem is when it expands, the rest of the navigation menu (links and headline) moves as well.

When I made sign up button animated, I thought that only the button is expanded while the rest of the navigation menu remains unaffected by expanded button.

Here is the navigation bar in HTML and here are tags, id and classes related to the navigation menu in CSS.

I would appreciate if you point me out the mistake and what should I have done instead.

```css
@keyframes expand {
    from {width: 125px;}
    to {width: 135px;}
}

#nav-bar {
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    float: inline-start;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    width:100%
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    float: left;
    display: flex;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 25px;
}

.logo {
    padding-top: 15px;
}

li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #111;
}

li a:hover {
    color: #c83737;
}

.btn{
    position: relative;
    background-color: #c83737;
    width: 125px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.btn:hover {
    animation: expand 0.5s;
}

.btn a {

    color:#e3e3e3;
}

.btn a:hover{
    color:#e3e3e3;
}
```

```html
    <div id="nav-bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#opportunity">Opportunity</a></li>
            <li><a href="#lessons">Lessons</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="top-headline"><h1>Web Development Course</h1></div>
        <ul>
            <li><div class="btn"><a href="#sign-up">Sign Up!</a></div></li>
            <li class="logo"><img src="https://picsum.photos/64/64" alt="Web Dev Logo" width="64px"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: there are multiple techniques: 1. you could add and animate a margin to compensate for the width expansion, 2. you could use transform scale instead.
3. you could remove it, everybody hates this kind of animation :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  scale in your animation like this

```css
@keyframes expand {
  0% {scale: 1;}
  50% {scale: 1.2;}
  100% {scale: 1;}
}

#nav-bar {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  float: inline-start;
  justify-content: space-around;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  width:100%
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-top: 25px;
}

.logo {
  padding-top: 15px;
}

li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #111;
}

li a:hover {
  color: #c83737;
}

.btn{
  background-color: #c83737;
  width: 125px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn:hover {
  animation: expand 2s;
}

.btn a {

  color:#e3e3e3;
}

.btn a:hover{
  color:#e3e3e3;
}
```

```html
  <div id="nav-bar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#opportunity">Opportunity</a></li>
        <li><a href="#lessons">Lessons</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="top-headline"><h1>Web Development Course</h1></div>
    <ul>
        <li><div class="btn"><a href="#sign-up">Sign Up!</a></div></li>
        <li class="logo"><img src="https://picsum.photos/64/64" alt="Web Dev Logo" width="64px"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. The animation is different from what I attempted, but scaling the button does not affect other parts of navigation bar. That actually helps me learn a bit more about CSS

Comment: You are very welcome. Glad that it helped you. If you want to scalr only thé width you Can use instead of scaleX() scaleX()